# expressionengine won't display all entries

Tags: expressionengine

I'm trying to display a list of retailers on a client site.  The filtered list (by State) displays properly, but the 'show all' list doesn't.  Items that are missing from the 'show all' list are displaying in the filtered list, so I know it's not an issue with the entries themselves.

I checked the statuses - all seems to be correct, and I've checked that dynamic=no is set.

What am I missing?

EE v2.2.2, Build 20110801

Comment: Can you share your entries loop template code?

Comment: Sounds like you may be using categories for state, is that right? Or some other form of filtering? Are you using native categories functionality or an add-on?

Comment: Sorry for not providing a code example - I guess that would have been helpful. Dan's got the solution below. I am using categories for State, but only using them in the filtered list, not in the 'show all' list. Thanks Jean!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, ExpressionEngine set a limit of 100 entries so without a limit parameter set, it is the same as

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="100"}
```

To get all your entries to display set a high limit like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="999"}
```

That should have all your entries showing up!

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

I use limit="1000000" to make sure.